# How can I modify my setter method to update results?

Tags: java, setter

My current code takes in input from the console and returns the points, goal difference and team position. However the `points` and `goal_diff` variables keep resetting when the user continues with the game. I think something may be wrong with my setter method. Here's my code:

```
public class team {
    public String name;
    int points;
    private int goal_diff;
    public int score;

    public team(String anyname)
    {
        name = anyname;
    }

    public void setName(String newname){
        name = newname;
    }
    public void setscore(int newScore){
    score = newScore;
    }
    public String getName(){
    return name;
    }

    public void setgoal_diff (int newGD){
    goal_diff = newGD;
    }

    public int getGD(){
    return goal_diff;
    }

    public void setpoints(int oldpoints){
    points = +oldpoints;
    }

    public void setpoints1(int newpoints, int oldpoints){
    points = oldpoints + newpoints;
    }

    public int getpoints(){
    return points;
    }
    public int getscore(){
    return score;
    }

    public void printInfo()
    {
    System.out.print("Name: "+ getName());
    System.out.print(" Points: "+ getpoints());
    System.out.print(" GD: "+ getGD());
    System.out.println("");
    }   

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "Team: "+name + ": " +"Points: "+ points + " GD "+ goal_diff;}

       }
```

And here is the main class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    //name team1
    System.out.print("Please enter name for team 1 : "); 
    String in1 = sc.nextLine();
    team team1 = new team(in1); 
    team1.setName(in1);

    //name team2
    System.out.print("Please enter name for team 2 : "); 
    String in2 = sc.nextLine();
    team team2 = new team(in2);
    team2.setName(in2);
    //name team3
    System.out.print("Please enter name for team 3 : "); 
    String in3 = sc.nextLine();
    team team3 = new team(in3);
    team3.setName(in3);
    //name team 4
    System.out.print("Please enter name for team 4 : "); 
    String in4 = sc.nextLine();
    team team4 = new team(in4);
    team4.setName(in4);
    //teamnames array
    String [] teamnames={in1,in2,in3,in4};
    System.out.println("Do you want to play or exit? Please enter Y to continue playing or N to exit");
    String in0 = sc.nextLine();

    while(in0.equals("Y")||in0.equals("y")){
    //choose first two teams playing
    System.out.print("Please enter names and scores for playing teams 1 : ");
    String resultA = sc.nextLine();
    //String e = String.valueOf(resultA);
    String[] myword= resultA.split(" ");
      //List<String> playing1 = Arrays.asList(myword);

    int score1 = Integer.parseInt(myword[1]);
    int score2 = Integer.parseInt(myword[3]);
    String p1 =myword[0];
    //modify to make method

        while (!(check(p1,teamnames))){
            sc = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("please enter team from list");
            String newn = sc.nextLine();
            p1=newn;
        }
    /*chkteam(p1,teamnames);*/
    String p2 = myword[2];

    //method to check fr same team
    p2 = duplicate(p1,p2);



    //for 1st team
    if (p1.equals(team1.getName())){
        setting(team1,score1,score2);
    }
    else if (p1.equals(team2.getName())){
        setting(team2,score1,score2);
    }

    else if (p1.equals(team3.getName())){
        setting(team3,score1,score2);
    }

    else if (p1.equals(team4.getName())){
        setting(team4,score1,score2);
    }
    //for 2nd team

    if (p2.equals(team1.getName())){
        setting(team1,score2,score1);
    }
    else if (p2.equals(team2.getName())){
        setting(team2,score2,score1);
    }

    else if (p2.equals(team3.getName())){
        setting(team3,score2,score1);
    }

    else if (p2.equals(team4.getName())){
        setting(team4,score2,score1);
    }

    //choose next two teams playing
    System.out.print("Please enter next 2 teams playing : ");
    String resultB = in.nextLine();
    String f = String.valueOf(resultB);
    String[] myword1= f.split(" ");
    int score3 = Integer.parseInt(myword1[1]);
    int score4 = Integer.parseInt(myword1[3]);

    //:)
    String p3 = myword1[0];
    String p4 = myword1[2];

    p3 = duplicate(p1,p3);
    p3 = duplicate(p2,p3);
    p4 = duplicate(p1,p4);
    p4 = duplicate(p2,p4);
    p4 = duplicate(p3,p4);



//for 1st team
if (p3.equals(team1.getName())){
    setting(team1,score3,score4);

}
else if (p3.equals(team2.getName())){
    setting(team2,score3,score4);
}

else if (p3.equals(team3.getName())){
    setting(team3,score3,score4);
}

else if (p3.equals(team4.getName())){
    setting(team4,score3,score4);
}
//for 2nd team

if (p4.equals(team1.getName())){
    setting(team1,score4,score3);
}
else if (p4.equals(team2.getName())){
    setting(team2,score4,score3);
}

else if (p4.equals(team3.getName())){
    setting(team3,score4,score3);
}

else if (p4.equals(team4.getName())){
    setting(team4,score4,score3);
}
team [] teams = {team1,team2,team3,team4};


sortPoints(teams);}
/*else {System.out.print("Thank you for playing the game");};*/
}

//METHODS start here
public static String duplicate(String name1, String name2){
    while (name1.equals(name2)){
        System.out.print("team " + name1 +" has already been entered. Please enter a different team :");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        name2 = sc.nextLine();
}
    return name2;
}

/*public static String chkteam(String play, String []teamnames){
    while (!(check(play,teamnames))){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter team from list");
        String newn = sc.nextLine();
        play=newn;
        }
    return play;

    }*/


public static void setting(team ipteam,int score1, int score2){
    ipteam.setscore(score1);
    ipteam.setgoal_diff(score1-score2);
    if (score1 > score2){ipteam.setpoints(3);}
    else if (score1 == score2){ipteam.setpoints(1);}
    else {ipteam.setpoints(0);}
}

private static boolean isInteger(String s){

    try{
        Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true;}
    catch( Exception e ){
        return false;
    }}

private static boolean check(String teamname, String [] ar){
    boolean res=false;
    for (String x : ar){
        if (x.equals(teamname)){
            res=true;
        }
    }
    return res;
}



private static void sortPoints(team[] teams) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Arrays.sort(teams, new Comparator<team>() {
         int res = 0;   
         @Override
            public int compare(team o2, team o1) {
                if (o1.getpoints()>o2.getpoints()){
                    res =  1;
                }
                else if (o1.getpoints()<o2.getpoints()){
                     res = -1;
                }
                else if (o1.getpoints()== o2.getpoints()){
                     if (o1.getGD()>o2.getGD()){
                         res = 1;
                     }
                     else {
                         res = -1;
                     }
                }
                return res;
            }

        });
        printArr(teams);
}
private static void printArr(team[] teams) {
    for(team i : teams) {
        System.out.println(i);} 
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been in too much details in the main but this method looks funny:

```
public void setpoints(int oldpoints){
points = +oldpoints;
}
```

From what you describe shouldn't it be

```
public void setpoints(int oldpoints){
points +=oldpoints;
}
```